# Assign Fetch JSON response to property in constructor

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch

I have a class with this structure:

```
class MyClass{
    json;

    constructor(){

    }
}
```

I would like to assign my "json" property form an API request in the constructor as an Array.

I've tried all sorts of methods and even copied code snippets directly from other forums. In the debugger and from `console.log()`, I've confirmed that I'm actually getting a response and in the `Promise.prototype.then()` I was able to use the result. But I just can't get it assigned to a class property.

These examples don't work:

```
class MyClass{
    json;

    constructor(){
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json =>  {
                this.json = json;   // I've tried using "self" when not using the "=>" operator
            });
    }
}
```

```
class MyClass{
    json;

    constructor(){
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json =>  {
                this._setJson(json);
            });
    }

    _setJson(json){
        this.json = json;
    }
}
```

I've also tried initializing `json` as an Array and using `this.json.push(json)` or returning `json` as an Object.
All the times `this.json` never gets assigned and I get `ReferenceError: json is not defined↵    at eval (...`

I would like it to be assigned but clearly, it isn't.
Also, I'm using Chrome 75 if that makes any difference.
  - Thanks

Comment: How and when are you accessing/using that `json`? Take into account that the property will only have a value once the request is finished.

Comment: It's data critical to that class. I would like to use it later in the constructor as well as in other methods. I've tried throwing `async` and `await` keywords around, but I'll be the first to admit that I don't fully understand their implications.

Comment: I recommend you not to perform asynchronous tasks in class constructors. If the data you are fetching is vital for the class, I would fetch it outside of the class and, once the data is available, create an instance of the class passing it the data.

`asnyc` and `await` make your code look like it is synchronous and its easier to read but the code continues to be asynchronous so you would face the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how that turns out.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it's a sync issue. When I access a method from that object from the console - after everything has been run - I get `json` populated.

Comment: Yes, it is a timing issue.  See the answer in the question yours has been marked a duplicate of as it outlines the various choices you have.  Because your operation is asynchronous, it won't be done when the constructor returns and because you can't return a promise from the constructor (it has to return the object), you have to develop other ways of running the async operation or knowing when it's done.  That other answer outlines your choices.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure looks to be slightly off:

```js
class MyClass{
    constructor() {
        this.json = null;

        //fetch logic here
    }

    _setJson(json){
        this.json = json
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Field Declarations, Chrome 75 supports it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations

Answer (score 0):

When callback is executed `this` points to global scope instead of `MyClass` scope. To fix this issue, save object's context into some variable like `self`:

```
class MyClass {
    json;

    getJson() {
        return this.json;
    }

    constructor(myCallback) {
        var self = this;
        fetch("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed").then(function(response) {
            return response.json().then(function(json) {
                alert(this == myClassInstance); // false
                alert(self == myClassInstance); // true
                self.json = JSON.stringify(json);
                myCallback();
            });
        });
    }
}

var myCallBackImpl = () => { document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = myClassInstance.getJson(); }
var myClassInstance = new MyClass(myCallBackImpl);
```

Comment: As I've said "I've tried using "self" when not using the "=>" operator".

Comment: Even using arrow function it works properly. I have tested this snippet on Chrome 75.0.3770.

Comment: What does `myCallback` do? Because if I strip it out it behaves like my code, and my code doesn't have these callback stuff. Thanks

Comment: Callback is just an example, you can take it out of the code, but keep in mind that `json` will get a value when` fetch` finishes running

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it's a sync issue. When I access a method from that object from the console - after everything has been run - I get `json` populated. Thank you for all your help.